# Edit ListBoxItem based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a chatroom for a school project. In the chatroom there is a listbox that contains all the messages.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="msglistBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, Mode=OneWay}">
```

`Messages` is an `ObservableCollection` that contains all the Messages. The `Message`class has the sender name variable. The chatroom knows the `user_name` of the logged in user and the `user_name` of the user who sent any given message.

I want to add the option to edit a message, but I want to make sure that only the user who sent the message can do it. Ideally, the "edit" button would only be visible to the message sender, not any other user.

How can I add a button that allow the user to edit a message in the listbox?

And how can I make it so that only the user who sent the message can see that button?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your ListBoxItem template so it has a button and a TextBlock.

Your ListBox DataContext should be a list of a new class which will have a string(message) and a flag so it can change the message (bool) that will be initialize with your conditions. More or less like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChatTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAuthor}"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="yourNewClassList" ItemTemplate ="ChatTemplate" />
```

If you new more help just let me know

Comment: @Dor Birendorf if it solved your problem pls mark vote this as the answer :)